# Tracking down a StackOverflow in a Clojure program, contains SSCCE

Tags: clojure, stack-overflow, list-comprehension

I am having a hard time tracking down a stackoverflow error produced by my clojure implementation of the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm).

Below is my implementation of the algorithm itself, and here is a link to a SSCCE outlining the issue http://pastebin.com/gtpTT4B4.

```
(defn Bron-Kerbosch [r p x graph cliques]
  ;(println (str "R:" r " P:" p " X:" x " Clq:" cliques))
  (cond (and (empty? p) (empty? x)) (concat cliques r)
        :else
        (let [neigh (neighV graph (dec (count p)))]
          (loop [loop-clq '(cliques)
                 loop-cnt (dec (count p))
                 loop-p '(p)
                 loop-x '(x)]
            (cond (= -1 loop-cnt) loop-clq
                  :else
                  (recur (concat loop-clq 
                                 (Bron-Kerbosch (concat r loop-cnt) 
                                                (concat p neigh) 
                                                (filter (set x) neigh) 
                                                graph cliques))
                         (dec loop-cnt)
                         (filter (set p) loop-cnt)
                         (concat x loop-cnt)))))))
```

I would have to assume that the issue obviously lies within one of my two bootstrap conditions `(cond (and (empty? p) (empty? x))` and `(cond (= -1 loop-cnt)` because the function algorithm is recursive.

Though this assumes that I am building the lists `x r p` correctly. Judging by the output of the commented out print statement (cliques is always printed as an EmptyList) I assume that my list comprehension might also be the issue.

Along the same lines, the other issue I can somewhat see is that I am not actually calling the algorithm properly in the `BK-Call` function (in the SSCCEE).

My overall question is what is causing this? Though this is somewhat too open, another question that might lead me to my answer is how I might go about using the print statement on the first line.

When the print statement is uncommented it produces the output

```
R:clojure.lang.LazySeq@2044e0b9 P:clojure.lang.LazySeq@7f9700a5 X:clojure.lang.LazySeq@1 Clq:clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1
```

I assume that if I could see that `x r p` are at each call I might be able to see where the algorithm is going wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** The `neighV` function from the SSCCE

```
(defn neighV [graph nodenum]
  (let [ret-list (for [i (range (count graph)) :when (contains? (graph i) nodenum)] i)]
    ret-list))
```

**EDIT2:** Noisesmith's answers had gotten me closer to the solution and made sense to me. I wrapped all of my `concat` in `doall`. After trying to call the function again I was getting "Cannot cast Long to Seq" errors, I figured that these stemmed from trying to `concat` `loop-cnt` onto lists in the function

```
fptests.core> (BK-Call (sanity1))
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
fptests.core> (concat 1 '(2 3))
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
```

So I then wrapped each `loop-cnt` in a `'()` to turn it into a list before it is `concat`

```
fptests.core> (concat '(1) '(2 3))
(1 2 3)
```

Which, after I made all of these changes, I ended back at my stack overflow.. Here is the new `Bron-Kerbosch` function with all of the edits. I guess I now have the same questions as I did before..

Though the new ones are, did I implement that changes that I should have correctly, does the usage of `'()` make sense to fix the issue that came up after implementing noisesmith's changes?

```
(defn Bron-Kerbosch1 [r p x graph cliques]
  (cond (and (empty? p) (empty? x)) (doall (concat cliques r))
        :else
        (let [neigh (neighV graph (dec (count p)))]
          (loop [loop-clq '(cliques)
                 loop-cnt (dec (count p))
                 loop-p '(p)
                 loop-x '(x)]
            (cond (= -1 loop-cnt) loop-clq
                  :else
                  (recur (doall (concat loop-clq 
                                        (Bron-Kerbosch1 (doall (concat r '(loop-cnt))) 
                                                       (doall (concat p neigh)) 
                                                       (filter (set x) neigh) 
                                                       graph cliques)))
                         (dec loop-cnt)
                         (filter (set p) '(loop-cnt))
                         (doall (concat x '(loop-cnt)))))))))
```

**EDIT3:** After patiently waiting for my `prn` statements to stop (not sure why I put them in when I knew it was in a SO) I found that most if not all statements printed were along the lines of

```
"R:" (loop-cnt loop-cnt loop-cnt loop-cnt loop-cnt loop-cnt loop-cnt ...)
"P:" (range (count graph) 0 2 3) " X:" () " Clq:" ()
```

After inspecting this some I realized that I have not been recursively calling the function properly. I have been union'ing items to `P` instead of removing them. This causes `P` to continuously grow. This is most likely the cause of my stack overflow. Though there are still some issues. I still am creating a stackoverflow, yet again.

Once I fixed my issue of continuing to union to P my issue is that when I `concat` `loop-cnt` it is not, I guess to say, evaluated to a value but it stays as a variable name `loop-cnt`. I suspect that my stack overflow now lies with my bootstrap condition not being met because it cannot be met if `loop-cnt` is not evaluated to a number.

So I think my issue now lies with `concat` `loop-cnt` to a list as a number and not a variable.

Comment: What does the output look like when the stack overflow occurs? You might want to look at a more idiomatic version of the BK algorithm in Clojure here: https://github.com/tgk/bron-kerbosch-in-clojure

Comment: What does the `neighV` function look like?

Comment: @BobJarvis I have added `neighV` in an edit to the question.

Comment: If you need to view the contents of these sequences you can use `doall` to realize the sequence, e.g. `(println (str "R:" (doall r) " P:" (doall p) " X:" (doall x) " Clq:" cliques))`.

Comment: `pr-str` is the right way to get the string for a lazy-seq in list form. Alternatively, using `prn` instead of `println` will print the readable version of each arg, if available.

Answer (score 0):

`concat` is lazy. Recursive calls that build `concat` on top of `concat`, without realizing any of the prior layers of laziness, each add to the size of the stack of calls that will be needed to realize the lazy-seq.

Does this concatenation need to be lazy at all? If not, wrap the calls to `concat` in calls to `doall`. This will make the concatenation eager, which reduces the size of the call stack needed to realize the final result, and thus eliminating the StackOverflowError.

Also, the correct way to print a lazy-seq and see the contents is `prn`, you can use `pr-str` to get the form of the value that `pr` or `prn` would use as a string, if needed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I guess some confusion comes now. If I evaluate `(concat '(1) '(2 3))` in the REPL it returns `(1 2 3)`. Why would I not receive something saying that the result is a lazy sequence instead of it evaluating? // So the reason that it does not stop is that it cannot perform any of the bootstrap conditions because the lazy sequences are not evaulated?

Comment: I have updated the question again, I have somehow managed to come back to my stack overflow. I added in your suggestions and ended up at another error trying to `concat` my loop counter (which represents a node) onto a list. I think I fixed that, and when ran, back to my stack overflow.

Comment: @KDecker, at least for nREPL, the REPL is implemented to default to printingthe values, realizing them if needed of a lazy sequence, even for an infinite lazy seq. (There is a way to control that.) To see whether something is a lazy seq, use `class`. `(class (concat '(1) '(2 3)))` ==> `clojure.lang.LazySeq`.

Comment: regarding the edits: no matter the value you assign to `cliques`, the value of `'(cliques)` will be a list containing a symbol. The job of `'` is to prevent any evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing quoted lists, I think.

For example, in `(defn Bron-Kerbosch1 [ ... ] ... )`, `'(cliques)` evaluates to a list containing the *symbol* `cliques`, not to a list containing the *argument* `cliques` as its one element. You want `(list cliques)` for that.

Similar cases abound.